# RealityKit animation resource animation notifies No bind target found for played animation when using repeatMode

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

When using RealityKit to play a FromToByAnimation using a generated AnimationResource, a message informing me that "No bind target found for played animation" when using repeatMode even though the animation is working mostly as expected.

The only issue that occurs is that AnimationTimingFunctions aren't working at all, but this seems unrelated. When removing the repeatMode, the message goes away, but so does the repeating of the animation.

The problem occurs in the following animation.

```
let from = Transform(rotation: .init(angle: .pi / 16, axis: [0, 0, 1]))
let to = Transform(rotation: .init(angle: .pi / 16, axis: [0, 0, -1]))
let animationDefinition = FromToByAnimation(from: from, to: to, duration: 1, timing: .easeInOut, bindTarget: .transform, repeatMode: .autoReverse)
if let animation = try? AnimationResource.generate(with: animationDefinition) {
    birdIdleModelEntity.playAnimation(animation)
}
```

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the message occurs on every repeatMode other than "none".